# numpy.genfromtxt return NaN values

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, genfromtxt

I am trying to plot second column of a csv file but second column returning the nan values. If I set the dtype= None or dtype= str will return the string values which at the end cause plotting in the wrong way in Y axis. any comment would appreciated.

second column in csv include values from 80-99% which save before like this snippet

> ```
>  numpy.savetxt('loss_acc_exp4.csv', numpy.c_[losses, ACCes], fmt=['%.4f', '%d %%'], header= "loss, acc", comments='', delimiter = ",")
> ```

Here is snippet for plot the csv file

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
acc_history = numpy.genfromtxt("loss_acc_exp4.csv", delimiter=",", 
skip_header=1, usecols=(1))


num_epochs = 151
epochs = range(1, num_epochs)

plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
plt.plot(epochs, acc_history[::2], '-b', label='Training accuracy') #plot odd rows
plt.plot(epochs, acc_history[1::2], '-r', label='Validation accuracy') # plot even rows
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlim(0.01,151)
plt.show()
```

Data in csv look like this

[image]

```
import pandas as pd


def convert_percent(val):
"""
Convert the percentage string to an actual floating point percent
- Remove %
- Divide by 100 to make decimal
"""
new_val = val.replace('%', '')
new_val = pd.Series([new_val]).astype(float)
return (new_val) / 100

acc_history = pd.read_csv("loss_acc_exp4.csv", delimiter=",", header=0, 
usecols=[1], dtype=None)
acc_history[:].apply(convert_percent)
```

it is returning `ValueError: ('setting an array element with a sequence.', 'occurred at index  acc')`

Comment: Can you share what your `loss_acc_exp4.csv` file looks like? This is necessary to know the format.

Comment: Default dtype is float.  Strings that don't fit are returned as nan.

Comment: @newkid sorry. my problem is about acc col.

Comment: @Neda can you add a snipped to your question ? It is not clear from your comment the formatting of the file ( newline, delimiters, precision etc )

Comment: if I get the dtype of acc_history for acc col is float64 for this line acc_history = numpy.genfromtxt("loss_acc_exp4.csv", delimiter=",", skip_header=1, usecols=(1))

Comment: It's the '%' character that keeps `genfromtxt` from converting the strings to numbers.  Try `float('91%')`.  You could load with `dtype=None`, and convert those strings yourself after.  Or write a converter to remove the '%' and return a float, e.g. `float(astr[:-1])`.  Or change the `savetxt` to omit the unnecessary '%'.

Comment: @hpaulj thank you for your comment. I tried many ways to remove the % and convert data to float, none of them works. the last thing I tried I added it to the question. any idea how can I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 2):

Using a converter:

```
def foo(astr):
    return float(astr[:-1])
In [296]: np.genfromtxt('test.csv', delimiter=',', converters={1:foo})
Out[296]: 
array([[ 0.8469, 99.    ],
       [ 0.3569, 98.    ],
       [ 0.9622, 97.    ],
       [ 0.4774, 96.    ],
       [ 0.381 , 95.    ]])
```